# is it a standard sql format for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

now I am write some sql in my rust code, I was wondering is it a standard SQL format with PostgreSQL? I have already searching from google but seems no one care about it, for example in Oracle, prefered to use UPPERCASE, for example, this sql:

```
select * from foo;
```

what should I write it?

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
select * from foo;
SELECT * FROM FOO;
```

which one is better or prefer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard and different people have different preferences. My suggestion would be to pick a format and then be consistent in using it. Also, try nor to name any tables, columns, etc. such that you need to quote the identifiers in order to use them. – [user6393](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6393/gsiems)

Just remember that code formatting is all about clarity and communication. Anything that obfuscates or makes people hop through unnatural hoops is bad. Anything that adds to the clarity is good. Focus there and you'll be OK. - [user6597](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6597/grant-fritchey)

Keywords are case-independent. Object names can be both sensitive and not, depends on DBMS and (in some DBMSs) on object quoting and some other settings. – [user150107](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)

If in doubt go with the convention [used in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-overview.html): SQL keywords in upper case, identifiers in lower case. – [user3684](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter)